# WordPress - How to have a static DIV that does not reload?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, static, load

At the top of my new WordPress Theme for a radio website, I want to have a DIV at the very top of the page which contains a small flash player which will play the radio stream.

I would like this DIV to be static and NOT reload every time the user changes pages.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Please provide a working demo on jsFiddle or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two ways to keep the music going

- Either you use frames, so top frame(preferably 0px height) never
  change and play the music
- or you can build your whole site with ajax you only change what you need to change and don't touck the player.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with ajax that you just pull the content on page change request via ajax and fill you DOM(except music player part) as per your requirement and then you need not to reload your music player.

Other wise if your music player code is the part of you `http` request then not one can stop it's re-loading.